# Table caption alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've a table with caption centered middle. At the right side of the caption, there is a link with refers to another page for detailed view. If my link text is too large, then the caption middle alignment is broken, it is pushed left. All I want to keep the caption at the middle regardless of the placement of link. That means, caption should be middle aligned.

[Problem Demo](http://www.bootply.com/oqvM4C347B)

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <table class="table">
    <caption>Table Caption<a class="detail-link">large link placed at right</a></caption>
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>City</th>
           <th>Pincode</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>Tanmay</td>
           <td>Bangalore</td>
           <td>560001</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Sachin</td>
           <td>Mumbai</td>
           <td>400003</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Uma</td>
           <td>Pune</td>
           <td>411027</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.detail-link {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Please include relevant code inside question, not just in an external site

Comment: if you are looking for solution like answers below then you can even do it more simply, change like this `<caption>Table Caption</caption><a class="detail-link">large link placed at right</a>` and set top margin to `detail-link` in minus with `display: inline`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using a div tag combined with some relative positioning as seen below.

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
<table class="table">
<caption>Table Caption</caption>
<div style="position:relative;float:right;top:20px;"><a href="link.html">text too long</a></div>
 <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>City</th>
       <th>Pincode</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>Tanmay</td>
       <td>Bangalore</td>
       <td>560001</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Sachin</td>
       <td>Mumbai</td>
       <td>400003</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Uma</td>
       <td>Pune</td>
       <td>411027</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Positioning it as absolute will achieve your requirement.

```
.detail-link {
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

CSS:

```
    .detail-link {
   float:right;
    width:30%;

}

  span{
    position:relative;
    left:26px;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <table class="table">
    <caption><span>Table Caption</span><a class="detail-link">large links asfasf asf asdf as at right</a></caption>
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>City</th>
           <th>Pincode</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>Tanmay</td>
           <td>Bangalore</td>
           <td>560001</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Sachin</td>
           <td>Mumbai</td>
           <td>400003</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Uma</td>
           <td>Pune</td>
           <td>411027</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
      span{position:relative;
        left:26px;   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

`Table Caption` also should `float:right;` and replace to after your link

**CSS:**

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.detail-link {
    float: right;
}
span {
  float:right;
  margin-right:15px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <table class="table">
    <caption><a class="detail-link">large link placed at right</a><span>Table Caption</span></caption>
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>City</th>
           <th>Pincode</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>Tanmay</td>
           <td>Bangalore</td>
           <td>560001</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Sachin</td>
           <td>Mumbai</td>
           <td>400003</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Uma</td>
           <td>Pune</td>
           <td>411027</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

i hope it's helpfull